# RMarkdown slidy_presentation indents last bullet within bootstrap grids

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap-3, r-markdown

I'm stumped by why the `last-child` of a list gets indented in a `slidy_presentation` when displayed in a bootstrap grid.

Here's a minimal .Rmd file. Note the specification of `theme: default` to provide me Bootstrap 3.

```
---
title: "Bullets in grid"
output: 
  slidy_presentation:
    theme: default
---

# Slide

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5" style="vertical-align:middle;">
I'm some content!
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
- Import with `readr`
- Reshape with `tidyr`
- Filter, modify and query with `dplyr`
- Visualise with `ggplot2`
  </div>
</div>

Content before end of slide.
```

And here's a screenshot of the offending indentation:

[image]

If I manually make a list it works fine:

```
---
title: "Bullets in grid"
output: 
  slidy_presentation:
    theme: default
---

# Slide

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-5" style="vertical-align:middle;">
I'm some content!
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
<ul>
<li>Import with `readr`</li>
<li> Reshape with `tidyr`</li>
<li>Filter, modify and query with `dplyr`</li>
<li>Visualise with `ggplot2`</li>
</ul>
  </div>
</div>

Content before end of slide.
```

Comment: It works for me using 3.4.3 and knitr 1.2.0 (from github).

Comment: @atiretoo hmm, I switched to the dev build of knitr to no avail. Here's my sessionInfo() https://pastebin.com/wPzKGRaT

Answer (score 1):

I was noticing some odd rendering issues when modifying your code.

Try removing the spaces before `</div>` after your content -- maybe try an extra line break, e.g:

```
...
- Visualise with `ggplot2`

</div>
...
```

Seem to fix it.